# How to unpack lists in a data.frame column?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have the following `data.frame` (output from `jsonlite` if you're curious):

```
id    person
01    list()
02    list(name = "John Doe", personId = "44)
```

The `person` column has a list. What I wanna do is unpack the lists and grab the name, something like this:

```
id    person.name
01    ""
02    "John Doe"
```

or expand the list elements into their own columns:

```
id    person.name    person.id
01    ""             "" 
02    "John Doe"     "44"
```

How do I do that?

Edit: how is this a duplicate question? I want all the columns in the same row. It's different from the last question

Comment: Can you show the dput output of the input example?

Comment: Can you do something as simple as `t(sapply(person, function(z) { len <- length(z); if (len == 0) c('','') else if (len == 1) c(z[[1]], '') else c(z[[1]], z[[2]]); }))`? You can `cbind` this to your `id` column ...